# Extracting all matches from different pyspark columns depending on some condition

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have to extract some codes from columns of a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
+---------+--------------------------------+--------------------+------+
|first    |second                          |third               |num   |
+---------+--------------------------------+--------------------+------+
|AB12a    |xxxxxx                          |some other data     |100000|
|yyyyyyy  |XYZ02, but possibly also GFH11b |Look at second col* |120000|
+---------+--------------------------------+--------------------+------+
```

The codes follow the regex `"^([A-Z]+[0-9]+[a-z]*)"` and are scattered across two columns (`first` and `second`) depending on whether the `third` column contains an asterisk. Since there can be more than one code in each column, I need all the regex matches in an array. In the example above, I need to extract `AB12a` from `first`, and `[XYZ02, GFH11b]` from `second`.

I found out that multiple matches are not supported by the default pyspark function `regexp_extract` (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24884), so I defined my own `regexp_extract_all` UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import re

def regexp_extract_all(s, pattern):
    pattern = re.compile(pattern, re.M)
    all_matches = re.findall(pattern, s)
    return all_matches

pattern = "^([A-Z]+[0-9]+[a-z]*)"

udf_regexp_extract_all = udf(regexp_extract_all, ArrayType(StringType()))
```

I managed to get the UDF working if I apply it on each column separately:

```
# this extracts AB12a from first
df = df.withColumn("code", udf_regexp_extract_all("first", lit(pattern)))

# this extracts [XYZ02, GFH11b] from second
df = df.withColumn("code", udf_regexp_extract_all("second", lit(pattern)))
```

But I get a `TypeError: expected string or buffer` when working in a when clause:

```
# this gives at runtime TypeError: expected string or buffer
df = df.withColumn("code", when(col("third").like("%*%"), 
                           udf_regexp_extract_all("second", lit(pattern)))
                           .otherwise(udf_regexp_extract_all("first", lit(pattern))))
```

I think I'm probably getting swamped with types at runtime, because something happens in a when clause that needs my UDF to be defined slightly differently.

Any idea?

Comment: I think instead of using like("*") you should use like("%*%")
Like THIS 

df = df.withColumn("code", when(col("third").like("%*%"), 
                           udf_regexp_extract_all("second", lit(pattern)))
                           .otherwise(udf_regexp_extract_all("first", lit(pattern))))

Comment: You're right, I typoed that. I edited it in the question, but it's not the root cause of the problem.

Comment: which spark version do you use bcoz for me spark 2.4+ is not giving any error on same code. and also try to remove ^ from a pattern to retrieve data as array.

Comment: I'm running 2.2.0, but the issue is null values possibly being present in one of the columns.

Comment: so for that can you please null value as well in your data frame to handle that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `TypeError` happens because there are null values in the columns. I didn't include them in the MWE, but it can (and does!) happen in real data.

An easy way to address this is an additional condition in the regex UDF to make sure `re.findall` only runs on string objects:

```
def regexp_extract_all(s, pattern):
    s = "" if s is None else s
    pattern = re.compile(pattern, re.M)
    all_matches = re.findall(pattern, s)
    return all_matches
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly fine. Just change the when condition as below

```
df.withColumn("code1", when(df.third.rlike("\*") == True, 
                           udf_regexp_extract_all("second", lit("([A-Z]+[0-9]+[a-z]*)")))
                           .otherwise(udf_regexp_extract_all("first", lit("([A-Z]+[0-9]+[a-z]*)")))).show(10, False)

+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------+------+-------+
|first  |second                         |third              |num   |code1  |
+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------+------+-------+
|AB12a  |xxxxxx                         |some other data    |100000|[AB12a]|
|yyyyyyy|XYZ02, but possibly also GFH11b|Look at second col*|120000|[XYZ02, GHF11b]|
+-------+-------------------------------+-------------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for double checking! Indeed, it does run right on the MWE above, but not on my real data. It made me investigate a little further, and I realized the problem was that there can be nulls in the first column which lead to the TypeError. I'll post this as an answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is kind of too verbose and can be simplified by some adjustments for better readability:

**Method-1: move logic into the udf**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\b([A-Z]+[0-9]+[a-z]*)\b')

# use s2 if s3 contains '*', otherwise use s1 (including s3 is NULL)
def regexp_extract_all(s1, s2, s3, pattern):
  try:
    return re.findall(pattern, s2 if '*' in (s3 or '') else s1)
  except:
    return []

udf_regexp_extract_all = udf(lambda x,y,z: regexp_extract_all(x, y, z, pattern), ArrayType(StringType()))

df.withColumn("code", udf_regexp_extract_all('first', 'second', 'third')).show()
#+-------+--------------------+-------------------+------+---------------+
#|  first|              second|              third|   num|           code|
#+-------+--------------------+-------------------+------+---------------+
#|  AB12a|              xxxxxx|    some other data|100000|        [AB12a]|
#|yyyyyyy|XYZ02, but possib...|Look at second col*|120000|[XYZ02, GFH11b]|
#|   null|                 111|                222|  1233|             []|
#+-------+--------------------+-------------------+------+---------------+
```

**Method-2: move when() into udf function argument**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, when, col

def regexp_extract_all(x, pattern):
    return re.findall(pattern, x or '')

udf_regexp_extract_all = udf(lambda x: regexp_extract_all(x, pattern), ArrayType(StringType()))

df.withColumn('code', udf_regexp_extract_all(when(col('third').like('%*%'), col('second')).otherwise(col('first')))) \
  .show()
```

Or using Spark SQL expression:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, expr

df.withColumn('code', udf_regexp_extract_all(expr("IF(third like '%*%', second, first)"))).show()
```

Comment: I'm always up for code styling suggestions -- thanks for the input.